# Calculate the future height of a element

Tags: javascript, html, css

My intent is to animate using CSS3 the transition of height of a element when a child div get expanded.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"> 
    <span>Small Conent</span>

    <div id="big">
      <p>
         This is way bigger content, will be visible after you have clicked the
         "Expand" button.
      </p>
      <p>It should animate up to the correct position.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button id="expand">Expand</button>
</div>
```

I came up with this hack, using `max-height`. But there are a couple of problems:

- The max-height must have a value
- The animation will start and stop according to the `max-height` given value, so if you insert a crazy value like `2000px` the animation will have a great delay.

To better illustrate the problem, I created a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/egDsE/3/

The only way of having a precise animation, is to insert the correct value of max-height.

My intention is to calculate using JavaScript (and JavaScript only) what the height of the parent will be once the child is expanded. But of course, I will need to calculate it before the actual transition takes place.

Is this possible? Only pure JS please.

Comment: An idea would be to clone your element, expand the clone, display it outside of the screen (you can't mesure items that aren't displayed, and obviously you don't want this clone to be seen), get its height, and hide it back (or destroy it).

Comment: you can use `height: auto;`

Comment: @Bartdude that's is a interesting solution. The problem is that it's really expensive on performance. And I need it to be calculated for several elements of the page. I'm afraid it's the only solution

Comment: @DOCTYPEHTML no, you can't animate a transition to `height: auto`.

Comment: It is indeed quite expensive, but AFAIK that's the only solution to get an accurate result...

Comment: Was a downvote really needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to do all of the that cloning and stuff...just give the element height auto, check the size and set the height back to 0.  It'll happen so fast the browser has no chance to repaint.

Now, this works like a charm, but the thing is that setting the height in Javascript immediately afterward will cause the transition to fail.  I just throw a 100ms timeout around it and then it works fine.

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById('expand').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var el = document.getElementById('big');
    if (!el.className) {
        el.className = 'expanded';
        document.getElementById('expand').innerHTML = 'Retract';
        var elH = getHeight(el);
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            el.style.height = elH+'px';
        }, 100);
    } else {
        el.className = '';
        el.style.height = '0';
        document.getElementById('expand').innerHTML = 'Expand';
    }
});

function getHeight(el) {
    el.style.height = 'auto';
    elHeight = el.offsetHeight;
    el.style.height = '0';
    return elHeight;
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 20px;
}
#big {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**HTML:** no changes to your markup

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="content"> <span>Small Conent</span>

        <div id="big">
            <p>This is way bigger content, will be visible after you have clicked the "Expand" button.</p>
            <p>It should animate up to the correct position.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="expand">Expand</button>
</div>
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/egDsE/9/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the Fiddle with the solution proposed in the comments by Bartdude, optimizing it for performances as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/egDsE/5/

```
var calculateHeight = function(e) {
    var outside = document.getElementById('outside');
    var clone = e.cloneNode(true);
    outside.appendChild(clone);
    var elHeight = outside.offsetHeight;
    outside.removeChild(clone);

    return elHeight;
}
```

The outside div have very basic css:

```
#outside {
    position: absolute;
    top: -1000;
    left: -1000;
}
```

I won't recommend this solution if image are involved, they would slow down the operation significantly.

Comment: This only seems to work for me once.  Each time thereafter, it cuts the content in half.

Answer (score 0):

not to be that guy but I would use LESS if you don't want to be as intensive and get this functionality

Comment: I'm actually using SASS in my projects, how would you do it in Less? I'm interested