# Animate div but keep height dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following scenario on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psax3fge/

D FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/psax3fge/1/

Basically its a `div` that has some info in it. The info is 3 separate `divs` that are `inline block`, they will be next to each other if there is enough room but will stack underneath each other when the Windows is made smaller

I want this div to be `hidden` until a button is clicked where the div slides down. I know not setting the height property will make the div have a fluid height (height gets bigger as things stack underneath each other). However, when I animate it with jQuery, I have to set a height.

Is there a way to do this without losing the fluidity of the div? An alternative is to not animate the div and just make it visible/hidden on button click, but I'd really like to use the animation

Comment: common question, but no straightforward solution. a frequent work-around is to animate `max-height` instead of `height` and set it to some value that you "know" will be large enough to accommodate your content.

Comment: Why not look at the width of the browser window and set the height based on that?

Comment: @JamesBlack I thought of that too, but wanted to know if theres a more straightforward way

Comment: My answer here is pure JS, but same concept applies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634464/calculate-the-future-height-of-a-element/24640212#24640212.  Just set the height to auto, get the height value and set it back to 0.

Comment: @jme11 i tried your demo, the expanding section doesn't get bigger when the window resizes. It stays the same height

Comment: You'd have to use the animation complete callback to set the height to auto.  http://jsfiddle.net/psax3fge/6/  Just to show you that it is possible.  However, the slideToggle option is much simpler so if it works for you, go for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 4: http://jsfiddle.net/psax3fge/4/

Leave the `.container` div height to auto and remove the overflow from it.
Now you can use the `slideToggle` function of the jQuery to show and hide the `.container`.
P.S you can set `display:none` to `container` in initialization.

Comment: very nice, I will use this!